# Is there an IntelliSense option / addon to show parameter name on mouse over?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Currently, if I stop mouse over the second parameter of a method like `MethodA(true, false)`, the tooltip will show that it is `System.Boolean` and some other uninteresting information. Is there an option or a 3rd party addon to display the parameter name and type instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to use more than just the mouse, Ctrl-Shift-Space will display parameter information.

(Unfortunately the built-in Intellisense only shows one overload at a time - one of the things I like about ReSharper is that it will offer you a list.)

Comment: Thanks, I know about Ctrl+Shift+Space but was wondering if there is anything to improve the tooltip.